# What's the best way to work with multiple combinations in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project using a client API where I need to update the status for some item based on multiple fields (3 at the moment, but it may be extensible later on if I decide to add more features).

So, basically it's something similar to having:

```
var field1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd',...] //there are about 9 values
var field2 = ['i', 'ii', 'iii', 'iv',...] //there are about 11 values
var field3 = [1, 2, 3, 4,...] //there are more than 30 values
```

A valid flow example would be:

User updates an item of type `a` with the value `i`, which will select by default a dependent value of `1` for the value `i`. All this will trigger the update of an item of type `b` (that is a child or parent for item `a`) with the same value `i` or another `ii` and a dependent value for `i` or `ii` of `1` or `2` (it can be the same or a totally different value for the last field).

Additional info:

Not all the possible combinations of values between fields is actually possible.
value `a` from `field1` for instance has a range between 1 and 4 values from `field2`, and each `field2` value has again a range between 1 and 6 values from `field3`.

The solution with that I came up so far was to use nested `switch` statements, but this leads to a huge section of unreadable and prone to errors code.

Another thing that I did, was to create a literal object, e.g.:

```
function getItem(value1, value2, value3) {
    var firstValues = {
        a : function() {
            return "a";
        }
        ....
    }
    var secondValues = {
        i : function() {
            return "i";
        }
        ....
    }
    var thirdValues = {
        1 : function() {
            return "1";
        }
        ....
    }
    var final = {
        Field1 : firstValues[value1](),
        Field2 : secondValues[value2](),
        Field3 : thirdValues[value3](),
    }
    return final;
}
```

But still need to add some `switch`s in order to make sure that everything is correct.

Any help on how I could tackle this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Very complicated logic, but generally your question is - I have three (or more) arrays, but it should be list (or tree) of objects. How I can deal with it?

1. Can you redo (change) API? If so, redo it, and your problem will disappear.
2. Think about your data structure - top level components, child components, describe this classes
3. Make factory object, that will process your distributed data and return from it list (or tree) of objects
4. ... ?
5. Profit